# Can a feature be shared between epics?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, cmmi

I am new to using TFS.

I have created two epics (With features under them):

1. [Epic]Workflow 1

   1. [Feature]Screen A
   2. [Feature]Screen B
   3. [Feature]Screen C
2. [Epic]Workflow 2

   1. [Feature]Screen X
   2. [Feature]Screen B
   3. [Feature]Screen C

How can I "share" the features "Screen B" and "Screen C" between the two epics? Or how else to organise this hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot "Share" the features directly like the hierarchy you mentioned, because a work item can have only one Parent link.

As a workaround, you can create a copy of the Feature work items, then add parent link to another Epic.

For example in you scenario:

1. Create a copy of `[Feature]Screen B` and `[Feature]Screen C`
2. Remove the `Parent link` to `[Epic]Workflow 1` for these copied
   Features
3. Add `Parent link` to `[Epic]Workflow 2`

[image]

Comment: @nakiya Have you resolved your issue by above workaround? any update?